# get column names in bigquery based on the column value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to get the column names when we only know the column values.

[image]

So lets say I have the above table and I want to write a *big query* code to get the all column names which contains **Sam**

Can anybody pls help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Consider below simple solution

```
select arr[safe_offset(1)] value, 
  string_agg(arr[offset(0)], ', ') columns
from your_table t,
unnest(regexp_extract_all(to_json_string(t), r'"\w+":"\w+"')) kv,
unnest([struct(split(trim(kv, '"'), '":"') as arr)])
group by value
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

or you can use below if you want only specific names

```
select arr[safe_offset(1)] value, 
  string_agg(arr[offset(0)], ', ') columns
from your_table t,
unnest(regexp_extract_all(to_json_string(t), r'"\w+":"\w+"')) kv,
unnest([struct(split(trim(kv, '"'), '":"') as arr)])
group by value
having value in ('Sam', 'Mac')
```

with output

[image]

Comment: It is giving multiple time the same column name and also, I am simply looking for list of column names to be shown in single column

Comment: isn't this as simple as just removing first column from select list and adding distinct to string_agg? i gave you more assuming you will be able to adopt it to whatever exactly your use case. if still problem - let me know :o)